# how to execute lines coming from a grep result?

Tags: bash, grep

I've got a text file with certain installation instructions, and I know I can grep for a unique occurrence in the file. For example, the text file has something like:

```
MYDIR=`find /home/user -name somedir`
export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:$MYDIR
```

In bash, how can I execute the lines after a grep in the file?
Something like:

```
execute result from "grep somedir INSTALLFILE"
execute result from "grep 'export PERL5LIB' INSTALLFILE"
```

Comment: Isn't automatic execution in this fashion a teensy bit dangerous?

Comment: @Faheem and @avilella: More than a teensy bit, rather dangerous indeed! Also, somewhat fragile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions:

- you have control over this file and are not in danger of malicious code
- you want to set these variables your current shell

You could redirect your commands to a temp file and execute that:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
{
    grep somedir INSTALLFILE
    grep 'export PERL5LIB' INSTALLFILE
} > "$tmp"
. "$tmp"
```

Or you could evaluate the results

```
eval "$(grep somedir INSTALLFILE)"
eval "$(grep 'export PERL5LIB' INSTALLFILE)"
```

---

Updating an old answer. What I would do today is use a process substitution:

```
source <(
    grep somedir INSTALLFILE
    grep 'export PERL5LIB' INSTALLFILE
)
```

Comment: Note that for `source <(...)`, you need bash 4 or above. It didn't work with older versions (zsh was OK though).

Answer (score 14):

To evaluate the lines in a separate shell process:

```
grep somedir INSTALLFILE | sh
```

To evaluate the lines in the running shell process:

```
eval "$(grep somedir INSTALLFILE)"
```

Comment: +1 for being the the only one to see the forest through the trees. Hereby deleting my answer. @avilella: for convenience you can use `-A 1` or `-B 1` as flags on one or the other of your `grep`s to fetch both lines with one grep and use that in either of @Gilles solutions.

Comment: Note that on some systems `sh` may be a symlink to another shell instead of the one you were expecting, so results could be unpredictable. To be safe, specific the exact shell you're expecting, e.g. `grep somedir INSTALLFILE | bash`

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using the 'exec' feature of find as in:

```
find somedir -name INSTALLFILE -exec {}\;
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking to execute the results that come back grom grep, not the run every result that comes back from find.